# Power BI embedded with on premises data

Tags: azure, powerbi

I wanted to use Power BI visualization in my web app project. I followed the documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/) and succeeded; however the data here is static and I have to upload a new pbix file just to refresh the data and have new entries reflect on the report.

I understand that Power BI Embedded is still in preview, but is it possible for the data to be always updated or to schedule a refresh period?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to refresh data currently is to use direct query against a cloud source. We are currently working on more options.

Comment: Is there a way to point a Direct Query report to an external (No Azure) SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

As above, I have implemented this and you need to use Direct Query and also use the option to add the connection credentials. Otherwise as you have seen the data does not update. The only way to change to direct query from import is to completely rebuild your report so hopefully you havent gone too far. With direct query, there is also quite a few limitations in comparison to import method, like calculated columns and relationships being mostly one way.

I also found out the hard way...